# Should I tell a potential employer that I'm moving abroad in ~6 months?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, new-job, negotiation

Here's the situation. I'm in the IT industry, currently unemployed, and have been interviewing for a couple of weeks now. A few days ago I received my dream job offer at an industry leader (let's call it company X), and it requires that I move abroad. There's no time set yet, but my guess is that I have around 4 to 6 months until that moment.

I want to decide what I'm going to do in that time. I've narrowed it down to two options.

1. I asked an ex employer (I was laid off back then) whether they had any projects I could work on in that timeframe, and they said yes, and they'd be happy to bring me on board. They know that I will be moving abroad. The only reason I'd like to work for them is because I like the workplace in general, and because I know the tech stack, but this tech stack is not the one I will be using in X.
2. Company B i'm in the middle of the interview process, with three interviews ahead. This is also a very good company to work for and if I hadn't received my dream offer this would have been my next dream offer.

So I guess I have two questions:

- Is it a good move to pick company B, considering the stress of changing jobs and getting used to a new workplace? Or should I go with company A, where I would hit the ground running *and* be able to do all the paperwork required to move abroad without having to make up excuses for my abscenses?
- Should I tell company B that I'd be happy to work for them but that I'm moving to company X in a couple of months? The way I see it...

  - If I tell them the truth, they might value my honesty but probably not hire me.
  - If I don't tell them the truth, and they hire me, and then I quit, I might very well burn a bridge forever and I definitely don't want that.

Comment: I think you're right about not burning bridges by making folks feel they've been cheated. If you're only looking to temp, say so and accept that you are going to be paid and treated as a temp.

Answer (score 4):

> A few days ago I received my dream job offer at an industry leader
>   (let's call it company X), and it requires that I move abroad. There's
>   no time set yet, but my guess is that I have around 4 to 6 months
>   until that moment.

No, you didn't.

It's **not an offer** if there is no date attached to it. It's also not an offer if you didn't get a benefits/relocation package/contract to sign yet.

> Company B i'm in the middle of the interview process, with three
>   interviews ahead. This is also a very good company to work for and if
>   I hadn't received my dream offer this would have been my next dream
>   offer.

With three interviews left, this job is not in the bag either.

Do not disclose too much information at this stage.

> I might very well burn a bridge forever and I definitely don't want that.

You can not burn a bridge you haven't crossed yet.

Finish the interviews with company B. See if they offer you something. Refusing their offer after they extended you one is not burning a bridge. It's totally normal and happens pretty much all the time.

Definitely, do not stop sending out resumes and do not stop interviewing. Things go wrong all the time! Do not assume you have the job with company X yet. If you do stop looking, it will take that much longer to restart the recruitment process with someone else -- if things go wrong in the meantime.

Comment: "Do not assume you have the job with company X yet" - if the OP only reads one thing, it should be that...

Answer (score 2):

When thinking about a job that you believe will only last 4-6 months, you should be looking for a short-term contracting position (or a series of positions lasting until you move).

If that can be accommodated by your ex-employer that could work out well. If you are honest with Company B about leaving in 4-6 months then that could be fine too.

Otherwise, start looking for temp jobs.